# How can I change global database name in Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Control?

Tags: database, oracle

I have to change global database name in Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Control. How can I do that?

I was searching in google, but on every page they suggest to use sql.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Don't think you can - changing the database name (SID), to be done completely requires not just the database name change (recreate the control file) but also, most likely, updated listener configs, and backups. Not a trivial task, and probably a bit too out there for button pushing DBAs and their GUI/web app things.